# HTML - Scroll the table view horizontally with constant width of view

Tags: html

I've to create a web page which is of 800 pixels in width. So I'm using the following tag which is making the width of the view as 800.

```
<div style="width:800px">
```

This is working fine.

But sometimes, I've to show a table view which has 20 columns. When I am adding the table view  which is taking more than 800 pixels,

```
<table border=1>
```

the whole view is getting scrolled.

I just want the table to be scrolled as the width of the view is fixed to 800 pixels.

I tried using `<table border=1 width=800px>`, but its still not working.

Can some one point me to right tutorial or example to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `overflow-x: scroll` on div / table

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/EjQAh/1/)**

Comment: dont mind, can you show me the code please... i'm new to html.

Answer (score 0):

You might place your table within div like below and set **overflox-x:scroll** style to it.

```
<div style="width:800px; overflow-x:scroll">
  <table>
    // Your table content comes here.
  </table>
</div>
```

Hope, this one will help you!.